# найти слово в строке

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    char string[1000];
    std::cout << "Введите строку:";
    std::cin >> string;

    char word[1000];
    std::cout << "Введите слово:";
    std::cin >> word;

    int len_word = strlen(word);

    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(string); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= len_word; j++) {
            if (string[i] == word[j]) {
                i++;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
            if (j == len_word) {
                std::cout << "Слово найдено в строке.";
            }
        }
        
    }

    
}
```

Нужно найти слово в строке и в случае положительного результата вывести, что слово найдено, в противном - не найдено. Пытаюсь сделать это через char и через циклы. Если длинна строки равна длине слова - то выводит верно, в ином случае - выводит неверно. Где ошибка в цикле?

Comment: нужна встроенная функция или Вы хотите свою реализовать? Если встройка, то https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214314/get-a-substring-of-a-char

Comment: хотелось бы реализовать свою, доделав то, что делал)

Comment: Еле вспомнил название алгоритма, надеюсь сможет Вам помочь

Comment: для начала освоения C++ что-то очень тяжело и много... Думал это задача будет делаться легче

Comment: Для изучения C++ лучше попробуйте написать свой string на базе char[] с присвоением как у обычного string, с возможностью добавления и удаления элементов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть Алгоритм Кнута — Морриса — Пратта

Реализовывается на плюсах он примерно так. Как по мне, используя данный код Вы сможете встроить его в свою программу

```
// C++ program for implementation of KMP pattern searching
// algorithm
 
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
 
void computeLPSArray(char* pat, int M, int* lps);
 
// Prints occurrences of txt[] in pat[]
void KMPSearch(char* pat, char* txt)
{
    int M = strlen(pat);
    int N = strlen(txt);
 
    // create lps[] that will hold the longest prefix suffix
    // values for pattern
    int lps[M];
 
    // Preprocess the pattern (calculate lps[] array)
    computeLPSArray(pat, M, lps);
 
    int i = 0; // index for txt[]
    int j = 0; // index for pat[]
    while ((N - i) >= (M - j)) {
        if (pat[j] == txt[i]) {
            j++;
            i++;
        }
 
        if (j == M) {
            printf("Found pattern at index %d ", i - j);
            j = lps[j - 1];
        }
 
        // mismatch after j matches
        else if (i < N && pat[j] != txt[i]) {
            // Do not match lps[0..lps[j-1]] characters,
            // they will match anyway
            if (j != 0)
                j = lps[j - 1];
            else
                i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
 
// Fills lps[] for given pattern pat[0..M-1]
void computeLPSArray(char* pat, int M, int* lps)
{
    // length of the previous longest prefix suffix
    int len = 0;
 
    lps[0] = 0; // lps[0] is always 0
 
    // the loop calculates lps[i] for i = 1 to M-1
    int i = 1;
    while (i < M) {
        if (pat[i] == pat[len]) {
            len++;
            lps[i] = len;
            i++;
        }
        else // (pat[i] != pat[len])
        {
            // This is tricky. Consider the example.
            // AAACAAAA and i = 7. The idea is similar
            // to search step.
            if (len != 0) {
                len = lps[len - 1];
 
                // Also, note that we do not increment
                // i here
            }
            else // if (len == 0)
            {
                lps[i] = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
 
// Driver code
int main()
{
    char txt[] = "ABABDABACDABABCABAB";
    char pat[] = "ABABCABAB";
    KMPSearch(pat, txt);
    return 0;
}
```

Информация взята с https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kmp-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/